# onChange no longer fires

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have an onChange function that have been firing reliably for me for well over half a year since I created one, but starting today it just stopped firing altogether:

```
function onChange(e) {
  Logger.log("onChange event fired");
}
```

For the record onEdit still works. onChange trigger is installed. Wondering if it's just me or if Google has changed something to make this not work anymore.

Edit: Noticed that copying exact same code with same triggers onto a new Google Sheets makes it work, but it still doesn't work on original sheets.

Comment: If the code you supplied is still not working for you then I would consider moving to another container.  Or if you have an older account then it could be that they are in the process of moving your account to a work space account or what ever the hell they're calling them now.

Comment: Please add more details like if the trigger still exists, the % of errors and the last execution logs and in case that there are errors add the textual error message.

Comment: @Rubén, It's not that the trigger gives me an error with "failed"; I'd at least have something to go off of if that happened. It just doesn't fire at all with no logs whatsoever.

Comment: I have just created a new container with exact same triggers and code, as Cooper advised. It now works. Old container still same issue.

Comment: What is shown in the triggers page of the Google Apps Script project?

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup with the help of this script ...

```
function myTriggerSetup() {
  if(!isTrigger('onChange')) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange').forSpreadsheet(ss).onChange().create();  
  }
}
function isTrigger(funcName) {
  var r=false;
  if(funcName) {
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var allHandlers=[];
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++) {allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction())}
    if(allHandlers.indexOf(funcName)>-1) {r=true}
  }
  return r;
}
function onChange(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("onChange event fired");
}
```